# Can you override depends_on when extending service in docker compose?

Tags: docker-compose

When you extend a service located in another file is there a way to override the original services dependencies (not just add to the original dependencies)? This is probably not the normal use for extending services but curious if it's possible.

file1.yml

```
services:
  serviceA:
    image: someImage
    depends_on: serviceB
```

file2.yml

```
services:
  serviceC:
    extends:
      file: file1.yml
      service: serviceA
    depends_on: [] # I'm hoping for a way to clear out the dependencies from the referenced service
```